# A zero potential difference in a wire in a parallel circuit, but there is a problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I was studying parallel and series connections for circuit and came a cross a problem that could not understand.

Now look at this problem:

[image: parallel circuit problem]

lets say current (I) is coming from the left:

the current (I) will be separated looking for the lowest resistance (I mean Highest (I) will be at the lowest Resistance), but I1 will be equal to I2 since both resistors equal to 5 ohm and Voltage is constant in parallel circuit. the problem that no current should pass through the middle wire (the rotated one in the middle of the image) as Potential difference across its ends will be 0 for some reason that I do not understand.

Sorry for my very bad explanation but I really do not understand what I am saying.

Comment: Do you know [Wheatstone Bridge](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge&ved=2ahUKEwicis66zuzrAhXF8XMBHcIWDHMQmhMwDnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw0epPoX1Y25Orws7vd5Mty_)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem that no current should pass through the middle wire (the rotated one in the middle of the image) as Potential difference across its ends will be 0 for some reason that I do not understand.

Imagine you removed the middle wire. Now calculate the potentials at the two nodes where the wire was previously attached.

What's the potential difference between them?

Now imagine you placed the middle wire back in the circuit.

How does that affect the circuit?

Comment: Thanks actually that makes more sense to me.